# Serverless (AWS) schedule job to run every Monday

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to create a scheduled lambda job using the Serverless framework to run every Monday. Unfortunately when I try to deploy the lambda I get a   `An error occurred: CheckC66ServersEventsRuleSchedule1 - Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid. (Service: AmazonCloudWatchEvents; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 086a7e2f-ad06-47b2-ac2a-64cbbba094bf; Proxy: null).` error.

My schedule looks like the following:

```
  checkServers:
    handler: check-server-reboot/check-servers.checkServers
    memorySize: 128
    timeout: 300 # 5 minutes
    events:
      # Run when clock ticks over to Monday UTC
      - schedule:
          rate: cron(0 0 * * MON *)
```

This appears to be a [valid cron](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_*_*_MON) so I'm not sure why it's not being accepted in AWS. I tried `rate: cron(0 0 ? * MON *)` which deployed successfully but failed to run this morning.

Any ideas on what cron schedule needs to be placed? I had a look at the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) but it's not helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second result that successfully deployed is the right answer but also add `enabled: true`. I have found sometimes CloudWatch needs the explicit setting to enable the cron: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/schedule/

Comment: Interesting...let me try explicitly enabling it and see if that works. Thanks!

Comment: I think your suggestion was correct. I think what I had done was deployed it with enabled set to false, then I redeployed it and removed the `enabled` property assuming it would default it back to `true` but it didn't.